# springdata jpa find in collection

Tags: spring-data-jpa

here is a repository, and I want to find entity where menu_id in a collection, I think my function name is ok

```
@Repository
public interface MenuEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MenuEntity,Long>{
    ArrayList<MenuEntity> findByMenuIdIn(List<Long> menuId);
}
```

but I always get error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
```

> menu_id is @Entity menu
>
> as Long menu_id
>
> but in mysql type is bigint(20)
>
> so I got menu_id as a List of BigInteger so I got error

Comment: You should not use concrete types, please replace `ArrayList` with `List`

Comment: @Arek I tried, still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Ok look like `ArrayList<MenuEntity>` should be change to `List<MenuEntity>` because it is not in the collection class arraylist is in the abstract collection class you need to try that first. in case that might help

Below is my old answer

*I think your `findMyMenuIdIn(List<Long> menuId)` is not supported you need to make your own query using your service module you cannot implement this in the repository you can do `findByMenuId (Long menuId)` and make the service module iterate through this query.*

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods but the document says it is supported

Comment: AbstractCollection is a implement of Collection, still don't work for List<MenuEntity>

Answer (score 0):

Your method name `findByMenuIdIn(List<Long> menuid)` is indeed correct and is supported. I use it and it works for me. However the error you're getting has to do with the argument being passed into the method where you're calling it. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]` suggests that the second item in your collection might not be of type `Long`. Check and make sure all the elements in the collection (the argument to the method) are all of type `Long`. You may want to post the code snippet of where you call the method including how you create the collection here. I hope this helps!